# Apache deflate javascript compress ratio 1.00x

Tags: apache, gzip

If I ran gzip in CLI, I can get a good compression ratio:

```
bundle.js:     75.3% -- replaced with bundle.js.gz
```

But in Apache, even I set deflate, it did compress, but with same file size. Below is my Apache config:

```
LoadModule deflate_module libexec/apache2/mod_deflate.so
<IfModule deflate_module>
  DeflateCompressionLevel 9
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/plain text/css
  CustomLog /var/log/deflate_log DEFLATE
</IfModule>
```

Below is the response:

```
ETag    "8342b-53dc33d01d2c0-gzip"
Server  Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Content-Type    application/javascript
Last-Modified   Sat, 01 Oct 2016 01:00:35 GMT
Date    Sun, 02 Oct 2016 01:14:20 GMT
Connection  Keep-Alive
Vary    Accept-Encoding
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=98
Content-Encoding    gzip
Transfer-Encoding   Identity
```

The network transfer size is same as before, and the ratio is 1.00x. I narrowed it down to only js get not compressed, instead css get good compression ratio of 6.22x. Is there something wrong with the js file?

Comment: Actually it's Safari who mislead me. I opened the same page in Chrome, and can see it successfully compressed with correct size. Only Safari web checker shows incorrect information. Safari shows that it is compressed, but with 1.00x ratio, which is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I noticed there is no "content-length" header in the response. So I went back to check Apache document. It says:

> The DeflateBufferSize directive specifies the size in bytes of the
>   fragments that zlib should compress at one time. If the compressed
>   response size is bigger than the one specified by this directive then
>   httpd will switch to chunked encoding (HTTP header Transfer-Encoding
>   set to Chunked), with the side effect of not setting any
>   Content-Length HTTP header. This is particularly important when httpd
>   works behind reverse caching proxies or when httpd is configured with
>   mod_cache and mod_cache_disk because HTTP responses without any
>   Content-Length header might not be cached.

As my js file is 500k, much over the default 8k setting, so I added the following in conf file, now everything is good:

```
<IfModule deflate_module>
  SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript text/plain text/css
  DeflateBufferSize 8096000
</IfModule>
```